# Dealing decks in blackjack game error

Tags: python, python-3.x

So ive been trying to deal the cards, but whenever I call the deckDeal code it gives me a deck is not defined error. Any help with what is wrong with the code?

```
import os
import random
import sys
#------------Functions------------------
def hit_stay(hit):
    if hit == "yes":
        import random
    else:
    print("dealer's turn")

def endGame(false):
    while endGame == False:
        print("")
        sys.exit(0)

def createDeck():
    deck = ['jack of spades', 'queen of spades', 'king of spades', 'ace of spades', 'jack of hearts', 'queen of hearts', 'king of hearts', 'ace of hearts', 'jack of clubs', 'queen of clubs', 'king of clubs', 'ace of clubs', 'jack of diamonds', 'queen of diamonds', 'king of diamonds', 'ace of diamonds']
    values = range(2,11)
    for x in values:
        spades =  str(x) + " of spades"
        hearts = str(x) + " of hearts"
        clubs = str(x) + " of clubs"
        diamonds = str(x) +" of diamonds"
        deck.append(spades)
        deck.append(hearts)
        deck.append(clubs)
        deck.append(diamonds)
    return deck

def deckDeal(deck):
    dealerHand, playerHand = [], []
    cardsToDeal = 4
    while cardsToDeal > 0:
        if cardsToDeal % 2 == 0: playerHand.append(deck[0])
        else: dealerHand.append(deck[0])
        del deck[0]
        cardsToDeal -= 1
    return deck, playerHand, dealerHand
```

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback of the exception. Can you also fix your indentation please?

Comment: How are you *calling* `deckDeal`? Do you have enough elements in `deck`?

Comment: This is caused by the way you're calling the `deckDeal` function. Please post a full code sample so we can see how you're using these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the broken `hit_stay` function and needing to shuffle the deck, the code "appears" to work.  How were you calling it?  Here's a way that works:

```
>>> deckDeal(deck)
>>> deck = createDeck()
>>> deck
['jack of spades', 'queen of spades', 'king of spades', 'ace of spades', 'jack of hearts', 'queen of hearts', 'king of hearts', 'ace of hearts', 'jack of clubs', 'queen of clubs', 'king of clubs', 'ace of clubs', 'jack of diamonds', 'queen of diamonds', 'king of diamonds', 'ace of diamonds', '2 of spades', '2 of hearts', '2 of clubs', '2 of diamonds', '3 of spades', '3 of hearts', '3 of clubs', '3 of diamonds', '4 of spades', '4 of hearts', '4 of clubs', '4 of diamonds', '5 of spades', '5 of hearts', '5 of clubs', '5 of diamonds', '6 of spades', '6 of hearts', '6 of clubs', '6 of diamonds', '7 of spades', '7 of hearts', '7 of clubs', '7 of diamonds', '8 of spades', '8 of hearts', '8 of clubs', '8 of diamonds', '9 of spades', '9 of hearts', '9 of clubs', '9 of diamonds', '10 of spades', '10 of hearts', '10 of clubs', '10 of diamonds']
>>> deck,player,dealer = deckDeal(deck)
>>> len(deck)
48
>>> player
['jack of spades', 'king of spades']
>>> dealer
['queen of spades', 'ace of spades']
```